# Dynamically change bottom navigation icon based on drawer navigation icon

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to dynamically change the icon of the bottom tab bar icon to the icon of the drawer page i change to. When the drawer open and i select cards page i want the payment icon to change from `money` to `cards` icon. Is this possible to achieve ? thanks

bottom tab

```
const bottomtab = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
    home: {
        screen: home,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => <Icon name="home" color={tintColor} focused={focused} size={30} />,
        },
    },

    payment: {
        screen: paymentdrawerstack,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return{
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="money" color={tintColor} size={20} />,
            }

        },
    },
},
```

drawer nav

```
const paymentdrawerstack = createDrawerNavigator(
{
    balance: {
        screen: balance,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return{
                drawerIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
                    <Icon name="money" color={tintColor} focused={focused} size={20} />
                ),
                drawerLabel: 'balance',

            }

        },

    },
    cards: {
        screen: cards,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return{
                drawerIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
                    <Icon name="cards" color={tintColor} focused={focused} size={20} />
                ),
                drawerLabel: 'cards',

            }

        },

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use this function to get the active route:

```js
const getActiveRoute = route => {
    if (!route.routes || route.routes.length === 0 || route.index >= route.routes.length) {
        return route.routeName;
    }

    const childActiveRoute = route.routes[route.index];
    return getActiveRoute(childActiveRoute);
}
```

And then in `navigationOptions` of `payment`, check what the active route is, change the icon accordingly, like so:

```js
payment: {
  screen: paymentdrawerstack,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
    const name = getActiveRoute(navigation.state) === 'cards' ? 'cards' : 'money';
    return {
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name={name} color={tintColor} size={20} />,
    }
  },
},
```